# Get content type with PHP from database

Tags: nodes

I have created a content Type Student, I have imported the list of student with node import. Now I want to get the name, location and other values of the content type Student from my database. How can I do that with PHP? I have already created a simple module with a menu and block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't use **[Views](http://drupal.org/project/views)** module. This is exactly the purpose of this module. And if you are not so aware of all drupal's API, it will really save you a lot of time, and security in your website.

> This tool is essentially a smart query builder that, given enough information, can build the proper query, execute it, and display the results. It has four modes, plus a special mode, and provides an impressive amount of functionality from these modes.
>
> Among other things, Views can be used
>   to generate reports, create summaries,
>   and display collections of images and
>   other content.

Comment: OK, but how can I retrieve the view. Because I need the values of the student. I'm creating a genetic algorithm that assigns students to a internship. (automatic placement planning tool) Thanks for your friendly reply!

Comment: What is your question there ? Is it about "how do a display my view" ?

Comment: Yes, how can I get my view in my drupal module in PHP.

Comment: The purpose of a views is just to display contents. Views can generate page or blocks by default. You need to add a new "display" in views UI to be able to see that. For a "page display", you need to specify a page URL, for a block display, it generate a block that is available in the blocks section, in the admin. If you really want to "call" the views in a module, you should check the **[views_embed_view()](http://views-help.doc.logrus.com/help/views/embed)** function.

Comment: The question is not about displaying the students, but to retrieve their information. Presumably for some process (internship assignment).

Comment: That's corret mongolito404. Have you experience with that?

Answer (score 5):

To retrieve a Student node (in OO-lingo that would a Student instance), use [`node_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load/6). If you want to retrieve all Student nodes, you have to loop over the result of a database query like this

```
$results = db_query(db_rewrite_sql("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE type = 'student'"));
while($nid = db_result($results)) {
  $node = node_load($nid);
  // Do something with $node
}
```

If you have a lot of Student nodes, it's probably not a good idea to process all of them in a single run. If you really need to process all of them, you should use the [Batch API](http://drupal.org/node/180528).

Comment: Finaly the solution! Thanks! But, for the last time - how can I access these values from my student? Many thanks!

Comment: And how can I copy all the values in $node into an array of strings?

Comment: $node will be an object with the student data as properties, there is no need to copy them to a string or an array to use them. Install the Devel module and use dpm() to output $node and inspect its structure.